# What is a good way to "sandbox" Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, sandbox

Nowadays I hope to have 2 Ruby versions on the same machine, because some gems are good for 1.8.6 only and at the same time, 1.9.1 is fast and it is to try out with Rails 2.3.

Is there a good way to sandbox the two versions?  I installed 1.9.1 onto `C:\ruby` and 1.8.6 onto `C:\ruby1.8.6`, and change inside of `C:\ruby1.8.6\bin`

```
copy ruby.exe ruby186.exe
copy gem.bat gem186.bat
copy gem gem186
copy irb.bat irb186.bat
copy irb irb186
```

and also go into the `.bat` files and change the `C:\Ruby` into `C:\Ruby1.8.6` inside the files.

that seems like a good start to sandbox 2 different versions of Ruby.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [pik](http://github.com/vertiginous/pik/). It's similar to RVM which is a great tool to manage multiple Ruby sandboxes, but unfortunately is unavailable on Windows.k